# (#1064) - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I get an error when i import a `.sql` file. How do i fix it?

Query:

```
insert into authorized_users values (sha1('".$name."'), sha1('".$password."');
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Here is the code:

```
create table authorized_users ( name varchar(20), 
                                password varchar(40),
                                        primary key     (name)
                              );
insert into authorized_users values ( 'username', 
                                      'password' );

insert into authorized_users values ( 'testuser', 
                                      sha1('password') );

insert into authorized_users values (sha1('".$name."'), sha1('".$password."');
```

Comment: If you're importing a SQL file directly, you can't use PHP variables like that - if you're using PHP to import this file can you share that code?

Comment: Please update the question with your error as well

Comment: Unmatched parenthesis on the last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your code and end the line with a closing parenthesis )

```
insert into authorized_users values (sha1('".$name."'), sha1('".$password."'));
```

Comment: It's a parenthesis `)` not a bracket `]`

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `)` here, so change

```
insert into authorized_users values (sha1('".$name."'), sha1('".$password."');
```

to

```
insert into authorized_users values (sha1('".$name."'), sha1('".$password."'));
```

Comment: You might want to add the missing `)` is at the end.

Comment: `insert into authorized_users values (sha1('".$name."'), sha1('".$password."'));`

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to enclose `MySql` queries inside double-quotes so I can use the variables directly without open and closing tags.

---

## Answering to your question:

You missed the last parenthesis `)`

```
$myQuery = "insert into authorized_users values (sha1('$name'), sha1('$password'));";
```